# Javascript add specific value to existing string

Tags: javascript

I need create function for add new option with new value to existing string:

```
"<select class='multiselect'></select>"
```

Result:

```
"<select class='multiselect'><option>Value1</option><option>Value2</option></select>"
```

Comment: @urbz +1 for providing link.

Comment: Have you checked out [MDN: DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the string will always be: `"<select class='multiselect'></select>"`

You could use the `replace` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
var str = "<select class='multiselect'></select>",
    insert = "<option>Value1</option><option>Value2</option>";

return str.replace(/'>/, "'>" + insert );
```

This will return: `"<select class='multiselect'><option>Value1</option><option>Value2</option></select>"`

If you're open to using jQuery you could use `$.parseHTML`:

```
var nodeStr = $.parseHTML(str);

$(nodeStr).append( insert );
```